# How to bind react route to a shown dialog?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

React Router has a good tutorial on [Nested Routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/tutorial#nested-routes).

And it's pretty easy to create and understand.

However, I want to bind a route to a dialog.

Basically I have a list of customers at `/customers` and I have a `New` button on it. When it's clicked a form is shown inside a dialog. I'm using Material UI. I want to change the route to `/customers/create` route and as the result of that route change show the dialog. This means that even if users hit F5 and refresh the page, they would still see the form shown in the dialog.

I can't make it work. I created the nested `<Route />` definition:

```
<Routes>
    <Route path='/customers' element={<Customers />}>
        <Route path='create' element={<CreateCustomer />} />
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

And I also inserted an `<Outlet />` in my `Customers.js`:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom'

const Customers = () => {
    const [dialogIsShown, setDialogIsShown] = useState(false);
    return <div>
        <Button onClick={() => setDialogIsShown(true)}>Create</Button>
        {* customer creation component is here, inside a dialog *}
        <Dilog open={dialogIsShown}>
            <CreateCustomer />
        </Dialog>
        {* other UI parts *}
        <Outlet />
    </div>
}
```

And when I click the new button, I use `useNavigate` to change route. But nothing happens.

I'm stuck here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying/wanting to render `CreateCustomer` component in `Customers`, or in the `"/customers/create"` route rendered into the `Outlet`? Where are you using `useNavigate` hook? This seems like incomplete code based on your description.

Comment: @DrewReese, `Customers` is a page that is rendered. When route changes to `/customers/create` I want to show the creation dialog on top of the customers list. What is not clear about it? I'm using `useNavigate` inside my `Customers.js`.

Comment: What isn't clear about it? You've rendered the `CreateCustomer` component in two places (*the locations I pointed out*). So it sounds like you want only the one rendered on a route. You may want to move the `Dialog` component into that route as well then. I still don't see where any `useNavigate` hook is used in the `Customers` component.

Comment: @DrewReese, let's say it this way. Let's not consider my code. What I want is this. I have a list of customers and when the new button is clicked, I want a form to be shown in a dialog **AND** I want the route changed. This way when user hits F5, he will land back on the same form inside dialog. Can you help me by referring me to an example, or an article?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gathered that you want to click a button in the `Customer` component to navigate to the `"/customers/create"` route and render the `CreateCustomer` component into a `Dialog`. If this is correct then I believe the following should be close to what you are describing as desired behavior.

```
import { Outlet, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Customers = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div>
      ... customers list ...

      <Button onClick={() => navigate("create")}>Create</Button>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Render the dialog open by default when the route matches and the element is rendered.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/customers' element={<Customers />}>
    <Route
      path='create'
      element={(
        <Dialog open>
          <CreateCustomer />
        </Dialog>
      )}
    />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Comment: So, I think I realized the point. I should create the dialog **INSIDE** the `Route`, not inside the `Customers.js`. That's the key here. Thank you. I'm testing it now.